# How is a thought within a story within a story indicated?

Tags: italics

If a story is being told within a story so that it is italicized and a character within this sub-story expresses a thought, something normally italicized, how is that thought conveyed? I would think that one would place that thought in quotes.

Comment: *Typically to emphasize a part of italicized text you* remove italics *and then resume them.*

Comment: Keep increasing the tilt. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one uses italics to set apart a story in a story, one may use ordinary text within the italics to set apart the story within the story in the story.

Comment: and if inside the story there is another story in which has another story, this story would be in italics again :D